# Normal Distribution and Percentile Word Problem

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, percentile

The Graduate Record Examination (GRE) is a test required for admission to many 
U.S. graduate schools. Students’ scores on the quantitative portion of the GRE 
follow a normal distribution with mean 150 and standard deviation 8.8. A graduate school requires that students score above 160 to be admitted.

Question: B) What is the percentile rank of a student who earns a quantitative GRE score of 142?

Can you please help me solve this and explain how. Because I know with these questions you usually use the mew and standard deviation to get a z-score. But then the z scores give you the area to the left or right, but what about in this case where there is one student who got exactly 142...and how do I convert to a percentile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the percentage of students getting a score of 142 *or less* (either that or the percentage getting 142 *or more*, depending on the definition of percentile rank in your course notes).